# How to change default directory access for a web app?

Tags: php, redirect, default

Currently when I open the main URL xyz.com of my web app, it takes the web app to xyz.com/abc/index.php.

I have another directory called 'ghi' in addition to 'abc' in my web app.

I want the web app to open with xyz.com/ghi/index.php instead of xyz.com/abc/index.php.

How do I achieve this so that upon entering xyz.com in a browser, the web app is taken to xyz.com/ghi/index.php instead of xyz.com/abc/index.php?

Comment: Could you share any code that you have? It will be difficult to fix without some code examples (and this may be in your web server's config)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Create a file index.php inside xyz directory with following code:

```
<html>
 <a href="/ghi">Click Here</a>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

simply ,place it as the first line after   in index.php file

```
 header('location:xyz.com/ghi/index.php');
```

or else Cpanel and redirect to the URL

Answer (score 0):

I think you can (and should) achive this goal with using a .htaccess file..
Here is a sample generated via [this tool](http://www.htaccessredirect.net/)

```
//Rewrite to www
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example.com/ghi/index.php[nc]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.example.com/ghi/index.php/$1 [r=301,nc]
```

Hope this helps..